# Collectionview Flow layout with multiple size cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to accomplish a collectionview with different sized cells. I've seen a few 3rd party frameworks but wanted to see if I can go it alone. Here is what I am currently have, I'm just setting every 5th cell to be bigger.

How can I "add" another small cell on the row with the big cell so that there isn't that vertical gap there? Thanks a lot for any ideas!

[image: currently]